# Accessing dictionary key with multiple values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an assignment and for the first part, I am to access a text file which will have a list of production rules. I created a list of dictionaries from this text file:

```
x = y
x = y x
y = 0
y = 1
```

that looks like this:

```
myList = [{'x': 'y'}, {'x':'y x'}, {'y': 0}, {'y': 1}]
```

I want to find all the possible outputs when applying these rules. I am going to attempt to write code later that will go through and replace the nonterminal values and output a bunch of binary. However, for this dictionary:

```
{'x': 'y x'}
```

'y x' is all one string so I cannot replace y or x with anything unless I explicitly say

```
'y x' = some value
```

I have written this code and written a really bad test code to see if the computer can see if a value for a key exists:

```
prodList = []


for line in open('name of file', "r"):
    line = line.strip()
    lhs, rhs = line.split(' = ')
    myList.append({lhs:rhs})


if 'y' in myList[0].values():
    print True
```

Now if I run this it will print True and I could move on, but I can't seem to write code where if I wrote:

```
if 'y' in myList[1].values():
        print True
```

that it would be True.

I tried writing

```
myList.append({lhs:rhs.split()})
```

But that didn't help and I couldn't check for any values at all. Is there any way that I could have the list look like this:

```
myList = [{'x': 'y'}, {'x':'y', x'}, {'y': 0}, {'y': 1}]
```

So that if I wrote

```
if 'y' in myList[1].values():
     print True
```

it would return True?

If this sounds confusing, please let me know so I can try to clarify more.

I also tried to make a dictionary instead of a list of dictionaries by doing this:

```
for line in open('file.txt', "r"):
    line = line.strip()
    lhs, rhs = line.split(' = ')
    myDict[lhs] = rhs
```

but when I printed the dictionary, I only got this:

```
{'y': 1, 'x': 'x y'}
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do this but I can't seem to figure out a way that works.

I looked over the above code again and I was just looking at the list of values and not the values themselves.

My question now is how do I make the dictionary with multiple values for one key? When I run this code:

```
for line in open(fileName, "r"):
    line = line.strip()
    lhs, rhs = line.split(' = ')
    prodList[lhs] = rhs.split()

print prodList
```

I end up with just this:

```
{'y': [1], 'x': ['y', 'x']}
```

I'm not sure as to how I get this

```
myList = {'x': ['y'], 'x':['y', 'x'], 'y': [0], 'y':[1]}
```

Comment: A list of 1-key dictionaries is rarely a useful data format. It might be better to use a single dict mapping symbols to, say, lists of production rules.

Comment: check this out: `myList = [dict([tuple(line.strip().split(' = '))]) for line in open('file.txt')]`

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what kind of lookups you need to do on this data structure? The obvious implementation is a dictionary mapping from keys (`lhs` in your current code) to lists of values, one value per line with the same key. The values would also be lists, with one inner value per term in the input (`rhs.split()` in your code). You seem to have considered something similar to this, but rejected it for some poorly explained reason.

Comment: I just read over my code again and I realized that I just wasn't accessing my values the right way. user2357112 was right

Comment: Sorry about the multiple edits. I just figured it out using the dictionary's get method after some research.

Comment: @user3246701 could you answer your question then? It would be useful for other users.